# ruby regex and grouping

Tags: ruby, regex

I've got following text `'some-text-here'` and try to get the `'text'` word from it using groups.

If I use that expression `/some-(\w+)-here/` all works fine, but if I try to apply grouping to it `/some-(?<group_name>\w+)-here/` it's raise an error `Undefined (?...) sequence.`

What's I doing wrong?

(Ruby 1.9.2)

Upd: shame on me. It's all from my innatention. Yes, I've use RVM and my ruby version turned on 1.9.2. But I've tested that expression at http://rubular.com/ where it is written at the footer `Rubular runs on Ruby 1.8.7`. Ruby 1.8.7 and Ruby 1.9.2 have a different regular expression engine.
So my expression **works** on 1.9.2, but **does not** on 1.8.7

Comment: It works on my Ruby 1.9.2 just fine. You're sure you're on this version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For me that looks like you are looking at the wrong Ruby. Do you maybe have RVM installed?

1.9.2

```
>> RUBY_VERSION 
=> "1.9.2"
>> s='some-text-here' 
=> "some-text-here"
>> /some-(?<group_name>\w+)-here/ =~ s 
=> 0
>> group_name #=> "text"
```

1.8.7

```
>> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.8.7"
>> s='some-text-here'
=> "some-text-here"
>> /some-(?<group_name>\w+)-here/ =~ s
SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):2: undefined (?...) sequence: /some-(?<group_name>\w+)-here/
    from (irb):2
```

Comment: you got me thinking about the difference between versions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

These are my results with `1.9.2-p290`:

```rb
irb(main):004:0> "some-text-here".match(/some-(?<test>\w+)-here/)
=> #<MatchData "some-text-here" test:"text">
irb(main):005:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.2"
```