# Rake commands aborted / Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

I'm *pretty* sure I should be posting this here, but feel free to correct me if this belongs on something like Superuser.

Trying to setup this Ruby/Javascript app https://github.com/jamesu/tubehub - on my freshly formatted Linode.

Running: Ubuntu v10.04 LTS, Ruby v1.8.8dev, Rails v3.2.9, SQLite v3.6.22.

I appear to be close to successfully installing and launching this app after much troubleshooting, but the last bit I can't figure out yet is the "aborted" errors I get when running the rake commands, as shown in the README documentation.

```
root@li570-120:~/tubehub# rake db:seed
rake aborted!
/root/tubehub/util.rb:8: undefined (?...) sequence: /^(.*?)((?<!&)#|\#)(.*)$/
/root/tubehub/util.rb:9: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?:\#)(?<!&#)(?:\#)*(.*)$/
/root/tubehub/core.rb:37
/root/tubehub/core.rb:36:in `each'
/root/tubehub/core.rb:36
/root/tubehub/Rakefile:2
Tasks: TOP => db:seed => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

root@li570-120:~# rake db:load                                                                                                                                                                                                               
rake aborted!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This is my first foray into Ruby specifically, filtered through some "rake" docs but wasn't sure what I was looking at.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `root@li570-120:~# rake db:load` this one you run from home dir, not prroject dir.
`bundle install` run successfully?

Comment: @AnatoliyKukul bundle install works fine now after some troubleshooting. Just tried db:load in the home dir, but still aborted, saying it couldn't find the rakefile.

There appears to be a rakefile in tubehub dir, but it just tells me "Don't know how to build task 'db:load'"

Comment: Please run all tasks in project dir.
I don't see `db:load` task I only see `db:schema:load` https://github.com/jamesu/tubehub/blob/master/Rakefile#L30

Comment: @AnatoliyKukul - tried this but still no luck. http://pastebin.com/yMjW2qnv - not entirely sure what I'm looking at in the Rakefile, as I said I haven't used Ruby before, going in blind. There's probably something I missing, apologies.

Comment: Looks like you are using wrong Ruby version. `ruby -v` to find version. I think you should use 1.9.3

Comment: @anatoliykukul ruby 1.8.8dev (2012-12-02) [i686-linux] - obtained this from ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/stable-snapshot.tar.gz

wasn't aware that 1.9.3 was the latest. I'll give this a go before progressing.

Comment: example with similar error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276324/ruby-regex-and-grouping

Comment: @AnatoliyKukul - I've obtained new versions of ruby, but not sure how to point ubuntu to use that new version. I do ruby -v and it still spits out the 1.8.8dev - I can do like ruby1.9.1 -v for example. so I know it's there, just can't find a definitive answer on how to point default ruby to the new one.

Comment: I use https://rvm.io/ or https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv to manage ruby versions

Comment: You'll notice if you toss your regex into [rubular](http://rubular.com/), it shows that error when using Ruby 1.8.7 but that the regex is fine using Ruby 1.9.2

Edit: Oh, I see that the other question linked to above mentions this.

Comment: I've running updated versions of Ruby, Rails, rubygems, sqlite etc. - still having the same problems.

(root@li570-120:~/tubehub# rake db:load
(in /root/tubehub)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:load')

Comment: @user1103976 - thanks for your input. what are you referring to when you talk about the "regex"?

Comment: As per @AnatoliyKukul 's suggestion - "rake db:schema:load" got everything working correctly, and loaded all of the tables needed into the local database.

worked a treat - thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add an answer. 
Please use `rake db:schema:load` instead

Answer (score 0):

As per Anatoliy Kukul's suggestion - "rake db:schema:load" got everything working correctly, and loaded all of the tables needed into the local database.

worked a treat - thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Please add this comment under the comment section not as a answer. This may be misleading. Thanks